# 'Insertion Sort' for an Array made from a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I'm trying to do an 'Insertion Sort' for an Array made from a text file.

The first part of the program reads the text file assigns its context to string for a name and integer for a number. Because the format of the text file is as follows:

```
100
12345
Jane
Doe
12359
John
Doe
98765
James
Doe
```

So the first line in the text file states the total number Customers in the file. The next three lines are the Id, First Name, and Last Name of the customer.

Where I'm stuck with is on how I'm gonna set the 'InsertionSort' to pull the data from reformatted 'customers' list the code created in the first lines.

I feel like insertion sort would be the best bet for the customer list I have.
The following was the best example that I could find that would work best with the code. I kept getting stuck trying to get this formula to pull the info the 'customer list' and run the sorting.

```
void insertionSort()
{
    int j, temp;
    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > temp)
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

In the meantime I'll tackle the binary search method, and see what's up there.

The following code is the 'Program'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ProgramTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            //Creates Customers list
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            string fName, lName;
            int id;
            //Opens text file
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("customers.txt"))
            {
                 //ignores first line
                 string data = sr.ReadLine();
                 //reads data and assigns objects
                 while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     fName = data;
                     lName = sr.ReadLine();
                     id = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                     //creats customer class list 

                     customers.Add(new Customer() { customerId = id, fName = fName, lName = lName });
                 int choice;
            }
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main Menu\n");
                Console.WriteLine("1. List all Customers");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Sort by Customer ID");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Search by Customer ID");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Enter Choice:");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        listAll();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        insertionSort();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        binarySearch();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Dont Recognize Input.");
                        break;
                } while (choice != 4);

                //display the list as is from text file
                void listAll()
                {
                    foreach (var customer in customers)
                        Console.WriteLine(customer);
                }

                //sorts list from based on Customer ID lowest to highest
                void insertionSort()
                {

                }

                //can search by customer ID
                void binarySearch()
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is the 'Customer' class.

```
using System;

namespace ProgramTest{
{
    public class Customer
    {
        /// First Name String
        public string fName { get; set; }

        /// Last Mame String
        public string lName { get; set; }

        /// Customer ID
        public int customerId { get; set; }

        /// Return String
        public override string ToString()
        {
            //return $"{fName}, {lName}, {customerId.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')}";
            return $"{customerId}: {fName} {lName}";
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why not: `customers = customers.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();`

Comment: @RufusL for the customers line how would that change the output?

Comment: That line orders the customers by the `Id` property, ascending.

Comment: Unless this an exercise to learn sorting algorithms, then I agree with @Rufus to just use the build in LINQ sort and search functionality.

Comment: There's also `Array.Sort` for arrays and `List<T>` also has a `Sort` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ this can be easily achieved using your code as an example:

```
//sorts list from based on Customer ID lowest to highest
void insertionSort()
{
    customers = customers.OrderBy(x => x.customerId).ToList();
}

//can search by customer ID
void binarySearch()
{
    Console.Write("Customer ID to search:");
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.customerId == id);
    if (customer != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Customer not found");
    }

}
```